# Lando db-import is taking very long time to import database

Tags: database, docker, import, drupal-7, lando

I am using lando (`v3.0.0.rc-14`) along with docker CE (latest version) for my Drupal 7 site. I am trying to import database of file size uncomressed(`~4GB`) & compressed (`~900 MB`) using following command:

```
lando db-import db-name db-filename.sql

lando db-import db-name db-filename.sql.gz
```

But, this is not helping. Usually, this db-import is taking more than 24 hours to complete. Is this a problem with my version or my settings in .lando.yml file?

My CPU and Mem usage stats below:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                  
28334 1001      20   0 1435088 568912  15892 S   2.3  3.5   4:27.81 mysqld                                                                                                                                  
 3131 usersf     20   0  306928   9320   7172 S   1.7  0.1   0:38.15 gvfs-udisks2-vo                                                                                                                         
 2095 root      20   0 2434900  96804  39620 S   1.3  0.6   0:34.19 dockerd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these instructions

Disable writing barrier for the ext4 fs:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Here you’ll see something like this:

```
UUID=700a2404-f687-4ae2-a2d5-54291553551e / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

So you just need to add barrier=0

```
UUID=700a2404-f687-4ae2-a2d5-54291553551e / ext4 errors=remount-ro,barrier=0 0 1
```

Reboot your system.

Or try [any of the suggestions](https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/456)